# Python - Using Lambda in List.Sort

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, lambda

I am trying to sort a list of lists based on the 2nd element in the sub list.

Sample  Data:

```
 [[u'm3u33mm534o', 14, 23], [u'2w3dfbv333g', 20, 34], [u'7kv903nfjfr9', 0, 35]]
```

Sort:

```
 out.sort(key=lambda x: float(x[1]))
```

Error:

```
TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number
```

What is the issue here?

Comment: No issue with sample data. Something in real data is not a string or a number.

Comment: The most likely issue is that `out` contains something other than the sample data you show.

Comment: Yep, works for me with that sample data. If you can't easily narrow it down, replace the lambda with a regular function, stick a `try:except:` in there and print the element that fails.

Comment: okay ill try that but i'm new to python and i'm unfamiliar with lambda and how it works. What else would i use to sort on that sub list element?

Comment: @ExceptionLimeCat: Again, your code is fine. It works with the same data you are showing.

Comment: `operator.itemgetter(1)`

Comment: You are likely to get better help if you include an SSCCE (http://sscce.org/).

Comment: you guys were right I just found an anomaly in my data. fixed that and it worked. Thanks!

Comment: Just don't know why you need it to be `float`? Makes no sense to me.

Comment: @Kabie: `itemgetter` is simpler and cleaner (IMHO at least), but it won't convert the data to float.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Works perfectly for me... Your real list will most probably include an item where the second element is not convertible to a float, eg:

```
>>> out = [[u'test', None, 35], [u'7kv903nfjfr9', 0, 35], [u'm3u33mm534o', 14, 23], [u'2w3dfbv333g', 20, 34]]
>>> x = out.sort(key=lambda x: float(x[1]))
...
TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number
```

To debug, just do something like

```
for i in out:
    try:
        float(i[1])
    except TypeError:
        print "error is here:", i
```